# Access image header information on roslibjs side

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I can access an image of type opencv format and send it to a web browser using roslibjs library.

What I am not sure in is how to access the header information eg. header.stamp and header.frame_id on the roslibjs side of things. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

this is the c++ side of things

```
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr(new cv_bridge::CvImage);
  ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
  cv_ptr->encoding = "bgr8";
  cv_ptr->header.stamp = time;
  cv_ptr->header.frame_id = "/camera/image123";  
  cv_ptr->image = img;    
  image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
```

on the js side of things

```
var image_listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
      ros : ros,      
      name : '/camera/image/compressed',
      messageType : 'sensor_msgs/CompressedImage'
    });
    
    image_listener.subscribe(function(message) {      
      console.log("image listener event fired");      
      var imagedata = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + message.data;      
      document.getElementById("liveimage").src = imagedata;                             
    });
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363190/access-image-header-information-on-roslibjs-side/) by [Jt3d](https://answers.ros.org/users/58688/jt3d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

header.stamp should be accessible by message.header.stamp. Similarly, header.frame_id should be accessible by message.header.frame_id.

```
image_listener.subscribe(function(message) {      
  console.log("image listener event fired");      
  var imagedata = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + message.data;      
  document.getElementById("liveimage").src = imagedata;

  var stamp = message.header.stamp;                     
  var frame_id = message.header.frame_id;
});
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jt3d](https://answers.ros.org/users/58688/jt3d/) on 2020-10-11**:
Many thanks - for some reason the intellisene in visual studio code wasn't giving those options so I thought it was more complicated.